# ¿como puedo enviar un archivo excel por correo en un sp de sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de enviar una data en un Excel a un correo atraves de un sp en SQL server pero me da error al querer generar el Excel ya que al querer concatenar me da un error

```
DECLARE @Asunto NVARCHAR(255) = 'Resultado de la consulta'
DECLARE @Cuerpo NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'A continuación se encuentra el resultado de la consulta:'
DECLARE @Destinatario NVARCHAR(255) = 'correo@test.cl'
DECLARE @RutaArchivo NVARCHAR(255) = 'C:\Ruta\archivo.xlsx'
DECLARE @Consulta NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Usuario, Nombre from Ges_Usuarios'

-- Exportar los resultados de la consulta a un archivo de Excel
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;Database='+ @RutaArchivo , --Aqui se genera el error al querer concatenar
    'SELECT * FROM [Hoja1$]')
EXEC sp_executesql @Consulta

-- Enviar el archivo de Excel por correo
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'TuPerfilDeCorreo', -- Nombre de tu perfil de correo
    @recipients = @Destinatario,
    @subject = @Asunto,
    @body = @Cuerpo,
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @file_attachments = @RutaArchivo
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás merezca contemplarse usar Dynamic SQL. Algo así como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @ExcelPath NVARCHAR(255)
SET @ExcelPath = 'C:\Temp\Resultado.xlsx'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 
'INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @ExcelPath + ';HDR=YES'', 
''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')
SELECT * FROM UnaTabla'


EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```